# what causes a scene's schedule to run even after the scene is replaced?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scene

> i have a scene1 that is replaced by scene2

```
[[ccdirector shareddirector]replacescene:scene2]//scene2 replacement
```

> after doing some selection on scene2 i am again replacing the scene
>   again with scene1

```
[[ccdirector shareddirector]replacescene:scene1] //scene1 replacement
```

> but scene2's schedule is still running, and i havent really retained
>   anything in scene2, pls help me with this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only happen if your scene isn't released. That means, yes, you do retain it somehow. Keep in mind that adding an object to an NSArray or NSDictionary retains it.

Set a breakpoint in each scene's `-(void) dealloc` method, or add an NSLog/CCLOG line, to make sure the scene is properly deallocated.

I'm guessing from your code that you're actually holding on to the scene1 and scene2 objects. You should not do that. Instead, create a new instance of the scene class every time you change it, like so:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replacescene:[Scene2 node]];
```